# Entity Framework 6 - An expression services limit has been reached

Tags: c#, entity-framework, frameworks, entity-framework-6, entity

I have a question about EF. I have one DbSet like this:

```
 public class ToolsDbContext : DbContext
 {
        public DbSet<ToolsObject> ToolsObjects { get; set; }
 }
```

And also have lots of inherited clasees from ToolsObject. When I inherited another two classes  from ToolsObject I got this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Internal error: An expression
>   services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex
>   expressions in your query, and try to simplify them.

during this line of code:

```
foreach (var myObj in _Database.ToolsObjects)
{}
```

But it works when I get objects this way (for an inherited class):

```
foreach (var myObj in _Database.ToolsObjects.OfType<ToolsObjectChild>())
{}
```

So I think, I've reached the maximum (65535) of identifiers and constants that can be contained in a single expression of a query, because of many and complex inherited classes from the ToolsObject base class.

Is there some solution for this?